# Inventory Ratio

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem that for some reason I can not wrap my head around.

Question.

The inventory has **80** available slots.

Coal takes up 1 slot, and holds **25** ores.

Copper takes up 1 slot, and holds **10** ores.

If a bronze bar takes 2 copper and 1 coal ore to make, how many slots will coal and copper have to evenly make a FULL inventory of bars.

A simple Text Visual:

slots = []
coal = 25
copper = 10

[25][25]

[10][10][10][10][10]

[10][10][10][10][10]

This example uses 12 slots, with 2 being coal, and 10 being copper. This makes 50 bronze bars evenly since there are 50 coal and 100 copper ores.

Sorry for any confusion, I know it may be simple, but I can't seem to get my head around it. So how slots of coal and copper should you have to efficiently produce the most amount of bars with 80 available slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide your example by $2$ since both quantities are even.  Then you use six slots.  If you want to come out even, you can multiply by $13$ to get to $78$.  You can't come out even at $80$, but you can use one slot on each and get a bit more.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!